# How do I use netplan to link my lan port with my wan port?

Tags: router, netplan

This is part of a project to setup my  linux  machine with 2 nics as a router. The “routes” key in the below mentioned yaml configuration file is what I think I need to set in the yaml file. What value should I enter against the “to” key?

The following are the steps I took to configure network interfaces via netplan. I did not have the entries for the  routes key as they had no effect.

This is what the values used in my configuration file and commands represent:

wan0 — connected to the internet. Has dynamic IP address.

lan0 - dhcp and dns server for my local network. Has static ip 192.168.1.1

/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml - netplan configuration file.

Entered values in the yaml file:

`vi /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

```
  ethernets:
    wan0:
      dhcp4: true
    lan0:
      dhcp4: no
      ignore-carrier: true
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
      routes:
        - to: <what value should I enter here?>
        via: 192.168.1.1 
  version: 2
```

These are the actual entries in my yaml configuration file (without the routes: key)

```
  ethernets:
    wan0:
      dhcp4: true
    lan0:
      dhcp4: no
      ignore-carrier: true
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
  version: 2
```

Executed the following commands:

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

Additional information: Finally I gave up on netplan and took these steps to get the router working: I did do the steps I mentioned above to configure my network interfaces via netplan. Then, I did these steps:

1. Enabled ip forwarding:

`sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf`

`uncomment net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Saved the file and executed the following commands

`sudo sysctl -p`

`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` - to Check whether the value took effect

2. Configure firewall rules: executed these commands

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wan0 -j MASQUERADE`

`sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wan0 -o lan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i lan0 -o wan0 -j ACCEPT`

3. Install iptables-persistent (Needed so that above rules are persistent between boots)

`sudo apt install iptables-persistent`

`sudo bash -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"`